# What is consequence of parent class having virtual method but derived class has no virtual method?

Tags: c++, inheritance, coding-style

Note: I am not asking why a parent class need to have virtual method.

I remember something coding guideline like that(I don't remember well and just try to express as my own word,hope I have correct wording): if the parent class have virtual method,the derived class should also at least have one virtual method, even the derived class would not have derived class from itself, if the derived class really no need to have any virtual method, set destructor as virtual. The reason behind it is something like "prevent duplicate virtual table", what is it talking about?

And I also remember a related example like that:

```
class A{
    virtual f();
};

class B : public A{
};
```

B as no derived class, if B has no virtual method, the consequence is something like "any place that include B will have a duplicate virtual table generated by compiler" (also is just expressed from my impression), what is the meaning of that (if it is true)?

Comment: Same as if it were declared by not defined AFAIK That is, no compiler error until you try to call it somewhere.

Comment: You're going to have to do better than 'something like' and a whole lot of waffle. You're asking us to comment on a misremembered coding standard that you cannot cite or quote accurately. It's pointless. The stated reason "any place that include B will have a duplicate virtual table generated by compiler" is complete BS. There is at most only one vtable per class.

Answer (score 1):

Note the following:

- If the base class has a virtual member function other than a destructor, the derived class inherits that function.
- If the base class declares a member function as virtual, and the derived class declares a member function of the same name with the same argument types, then the derived class function is automatically virtual, and overrides the base class's function.
- If the base class has a virtual destructor, the derived class's destructor is automatically virtual, whether user-declared or not, and overrides the base class's destructor.

The example you gave is not in any way problematic. I would advise you to forget everything you think you remember about this coding standard.